# Sublime Text 2 php string variables

Tags: sublimetext2

I have recently started to use Sublime Text 2. I need to php string variables displayed in bold. In the default configuration file (preferences-settings-default) I didn't find these options. How can i solve it in Sublime Text 2?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the regex pattern you'll need to use:

```
{ "match": "\\$([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]+)",
  "name": "keyword.syntaxTypeAbbreviation",
  "captures": {
    "1": { "name": "moreSpecific.selectorName.syntaxTypeAbbreviation " }
  },
  "comment": "Variables like $PARAM1, $TM_SELECTION..."
}
```

Reference:-http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html#fine-tuning-matches